# Why isn't Wordpress' 'save_post_{$post->post_type}' action hook passing the correct number of arguments?

Tags: php, wordpress

According to the WordPress codex [save_post_{$post->post_type}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post_post-post_type/) should pass three arguments:

`do_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", int $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update )`

**Here is my code:**

```
add_action( 'save_post_guide', array($this, 'saveGuideMeta') );
function saveGuideMeta(int $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update) {
    if (isset($_POST['guide_keyword'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_ID, 'guide_keyword', sanitize_text_field($_POST['guide_keyword']));
    }
}
```

I literally copied the function signature to be sure, but it throws an `ArgumentCountError` when I save the post (so I know the function is being called and the hook is "working").

**The Exception**

`Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function saveGuideMeta(), 1 passed in public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288 and exactly 3 expected`

It's as if the `save_post_guide` hook is not passing the three arguments, only one.

I am simply attempting to update post meta when a post is saved. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [registered callback for the action hooked into](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) is passed the default `$accepted_args`; the value for that is 1.

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

This needs to be set to 3 to get all 3.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is in `functions.php`, then you might need to write action code as:

```
add_action( 'save_post_guide', 'saveGuideMeta' );
```

and if code is in plugin Class and you are calling action in the constructor of Class, then you need to make saveGuideMeta function as public as follows

```
public function saveGuideMeta(int $post_ID, WP_Post $post, bool $update) {
    if (isset($_POST['guide_keyword'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_ID, 'guide_keyword', sanitize_text_field($_POST['guide_keyword']));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I actually just discovered what the problem was. add_action has 2 more arguments: priority and # of accepted arguments passed.

So I had to change my add_action to `add_action( 'save_post_guide', array($this, 'saveGuideMeta'), 10, 3 );` -- that 3 tells it to pass three arguments. 

The more you know... ;)